# Borel structure/sets coming from strong operator topology vs norm topology

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces. Moreover, let $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be the space of bounded linear operators equipped with the standard operator norm topology, and $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,Y)$ the same space but with the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology).

> When do Borel $\sigma$-algebras generated by the operator norm
> topology and the strong operator topology coincide? In other words $$\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}(X,Y)) = \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,Y)).$$

**Some partial results:**

0. $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}(X,Y)) \supset \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,Y)) $ is trivial;
1. Under additional assumptions; that $X,Y$ are separable; it can be found along the lines of Lemma A.2 in [*A semi-invertible operator Oseledets theorem*; C. González-Tokman & A. Quas](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5609) that $\{T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y) : \|T\|\le r \}\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,Y))$ for all $r$. Therefore, if in addition $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is also separable (with respect to operator norm topology) then $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}(X,Y)) = \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,Y))$ should hold. Since, any open set will be the countable union of balls;
2. Another approach is to look at a special case when $Y=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,\mathbb{R})$ will become $X^*$ with the weak-* topology. Since, any Hausdorff topology weaker than the norm topology (such
   as the weak-* topology) is equal to the norm topology on a compact subset; $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R})){\restriction}_{A} = \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{s}}(X,\mathbb{R})){\restriction}_{A}$ for any compact $A$ in $\mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R})$.

I'm rather interested in some more general results concerning only assumption on $X$ and $Y$, not $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. References welcome, thanks in advance.